# No CART ID in Cookie/Context object in Prestashop

Tags: object, cookies, cart, prestashop-1.6

I'm having an issue about the id_cart on the Cookie/Context object. I have a custom payment module that needs to access the Cookie/Context object from Prestashop in order to validate the order.

Below is when I print the cookie object after purchasing an item on the shop that I'm working on. You can see that the id_cart is missing. 
[image]

This is also happening only when the customer already visited/purchased an order to the shop. If the shop was visited for the first time, the id_cart is in the object, but when you try to purchase an order again, the id_cart is missing. I already cleared the cache from the adminpanel and even in the FTP files and I also disable it for a while to test if its the cache that causing the problem but I still facing the issue. Note that since this is a payment module, the order wasn't created yet so the cookie/context object is the only reference to get the cart_id.

Below is the sample code in my custom payment module that calls the global cookie object and get the id_cart. It was the first time I encountered this issue. Everything is working fine before.

[image]

Please share your insights on this issue. It would be a big help for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your database, I had a similar issue, when I looked at my database, the AI (AUTO_INCREMENT) was not set for the primary key of the cart table.
By setting it, the problem is solved.
NB : Be attention for the existing cart ids.